# varnish 6 behavior no-data POST

Tags: varnish, curl

I'm facing a strange behavior on varnish 6, and I would need some advices to find out what's wrong. This occures on empty POST/PUT requests.

Everything is working well on recipe platform but fails on production plateform with error :

```
transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
```

Here is the detailed tests :

```
$ curl -v -X PUT --data "" "http://<prod-varnish-server>:81/"
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55ee8ab12f50)
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55ee8ab12f50)
* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 81 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ************
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 08:21:55 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Vary: cookie,authorization,Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Backend: web1
< X-ttl: 0.000
< X-Varnish: 463
< Age: 0
< Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.1)
< X-Debug-Served-By: front_nodes
< X-Debug-varnishHost: frd825p103fel.itc.integra.fr
< X-Debug-User-Hash:
< X-Debug-Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=86400
< X-Cache: MISS
< Cache-Control: public
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
* transfer closed with outstanding read data remaining
* Closing connection 0


$ curl -v -X PUT --data "" "http://<prod-apache-backend>:82/"
* Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55b5beda8f50)
*   Trying 10.10.10.11...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55b5beda8f50)
* Connected to 10.10.10.11 (10.10.10.11) port 82 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ************
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 08:22:29 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=86400
< Vary: cookie,authorization,Accept-Encoding
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<
 ... html code data


$ curl -v -X PUT --data "" "http://<rec-varnish-server>:81/"
*   Trying 10.10.10.10...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to 10.10.10.10 (10.10.10.10) port 81 (#0)
> PUT / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ************
> User-Agent: curl/7.52.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 0
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 29 Sep 2020 08:25:45 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Vary: cookie,authorization,Accept-Encoding
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< X-Backend: web2
< X-ttl: 0.000
< X-Varnish: 32777
< Age: 0
< Via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/6.0)
< X-Debug-Served-By: front_nodes
< X-Debug-varnishHost: INTEZPUBCACHE.itc.integra.fr
< X-Debug-User-Hash:
< X-Debug-Cache-Control: public, s-maxage=86400
< X-Cache: MISS
< Cache-Control: public
< Accept-Ranges: bytes
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
<
 ... html code data
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0
* Connection #0 to host 127.0.0.1 left intact
```

On production environment :

- varnishd (varnish-6.1.1 revision efc2f6c1536cf2272e471f5cff5f145239b19460)
- curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1d zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.5 libpsl/0.20.2 (+libidn2/2.0.5) libssh2/1.8.0 nghttp2/1.36.0 librtmp/2.3

On recipe environment :

- varnishd (varnish-6.0.6 revision 29a1a8243dbef3d973aec28dc90403188c1dc8e7)
- curl 7.52.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.52.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2q zlib/1.2.8 libidn2/0.16 libpsl/0.17.0 (+libidn2/0.16) libssh2/1.7.0 nghttp2/1.18.1 librtmp/2.3

Thank you

Comment: I notice you use `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to stream the data, instead of buffering the content and sending it out with a `Content-Length` header;

It seems as though a timeout was hit, and that the connection was closed, eventhough there was still content to send.

Can you attach the VCL code to your question, and an extract from `varnishlog -g request -q "ReqUrl eq '/'"`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, chunk data are caused by mod-deflate I think, however, the traffic will be open today, so I don't have enough time to investigate, as a workaround, I've piped the POST and PUT request (which is not a bad thing I think)